# Update stock quantity wocoommerce Daily with cron

Tags: php, woocommerce, cron, advanced-custom-fields, cron-task

I would like to update the stock of woocommerce products once a day. The quantity to be entered daily is given by an acf field present in each single product.

The products are variable, but they all have a single variation, so the stock is set only in the general tab of the product. So the stock is unique.

This is my code, but the update function returns me `false`, while the daily stock is correctly displayed in each product.

```
function tommix_custom_cron_schedule_two($schedules) {
    if (!isset($schedules["tommix_daily"]))
        $schedules["tommix_daily"] = array(
            'interval' => 86400,
            'display'  => __('Daily'),
        );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'tommix_custom_cron_schedule_two');

if (!wp_next_scheduled('wp_footer')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'tommix_daily', 'wp_footer');
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'tommix_cron_function');

function tommix_cron_function($post_id) {
    $daily_stock = get_field('al_giorno', $post_id);
    if (!empty($daily_stock)) {
        d($daily_stock);
        //update_post_meta($post_id,"_stock",$daily_stock);
        d(update_post_meta($post_id, "_stock", $daily_stock));
    }
}
```